# Timing JavaFX Canvas Application

Tags: performance, swing, javafx, graphics

I order to practice JavaFX, I built a simple app that draws [Sierpinski Triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SierpinskiTriangles extends Application {

    private final int PADDING = 5;
    private static int numberOfLevels;

    public static void launch(String... args){

        numberOfLevels = 8;

        if((args != null) && (args.length > 0)) {

            int num = -1;
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            numberOfLevels = (num > 0) ? num : numberOfLevels;
        }

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setOnCloseRequest((ae) -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setTitle("Sierpinski Triangles (fx)");

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING));

        Pane triPanel = new Triangles();

        BorderPane.setAlignment(triPanel, Pos.CENTER);
        mainPane.setCenter(triPanel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.centerOnScreen();

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    class Triangles  extends AnchorPane{

        private static final int PANEL_WIDTH =600, PANEL_HEIGHT = 600;
        private static final int TRI_WIDTH= 500, TRI_HEIGHT= 500;
        private static final int SIDE_GAP = (PANEL_WIDTH - TRI_WIDTH)/2;
        private static final int TOP_GAP = (PANEL_HEIGHT - TRI_HEIGHT)/2;
        private int countTriangles;
        private long startTime;
        private Point2D top, left, right;

        private Canvas canvas;
        private GraphicsContext gc;

        Triangles(){

            setPrefSize(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);

            canvas = getCanvas();
            gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            getChildren().add(canvas);
            draw(numberOfLevels);
        }

        void draw(int numberLevels) {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    clearCanvas();
                    setStartPoints();

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    countTriangles = 0;

                    RunTask task = new RunTask(numberLevels, top, left, right);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                    thread.start();
                }
            });

        }

        private void drawTriangle( int levels, Point2D top, Point2D left, Point2D right) {

            if(levels < 0) {//add stop criteria
                return ;
            }

            gc.strokePolygon( //implementing with strokeLine did not make much difference
                    new double[]{
                            top.getX(),left.getX(),right.getX()
                    },
                    new double[]{
                            top.getY(),left.getY(), right.getY()
                    },3
                    );

            countTriangles++;

            //Get the midpoint on each edge in the triangle
            Point2D p12 = midpoint(top, left);
            Point2D p23 = midpoint(left, right);
            Point2D p31 = midpoint(right, top);

            // recurse on 3 triangular areas
            drawTriangle(levels - 1, top, p12, p31);
            drawTriangle(levels - 1, p12, left, p23);
            drawTriangle(levels - 1, p31, p23, right);
        }

        private void setStartPoints() {

            top = new Point2D(getPrefWidth()/2, TOP_GAP);
            left = new Point2D(SIDE_GAP, TOP_GAP + TRI_HEIGHT);
            right = new Point2D(SIDE_GAP + TRI_WIDTH, TOP_GAP + TRI_WIDTH);
        }

        private Point2D midpoint(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {

            return new Point2D((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) /
                    2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2);
        }

        private void updateGraphics(boolean success){

            if(success) {

                gc.fillText("Number of triangles: "+ countTriangles,5,15);
                gc.fillText("Time : "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()- startTime)+ " mili seconds", 5,35);
                gc.fillText("Levels: "+ numberOfLevels,5,55);
            }

            System.out.println("Completed after: "+
                    (System.currentTimeMillis()- startTime)+ " mili seconds"
                    +"  Triangles: " + countTriangles  +"  Failed: "+ !success );
        }

        private Canvas getCanvas() {

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            canvas.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.RED);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setLineWidth(0.3f);

            return canvas;
        }

        private void clearCanvas() {

            gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        }

        class RunTask extends Task<Void>{

            private int levels;
            private Point2D top, left;
            private Point2D right;

            RunTask(int levels, Point2D top, Point2D left, Point2D right){

                this.levels = levels;
                this.top = top;
                this.left = left;
                this.right = right;

                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                countTriangles = 0;
            }

            @Override public Void call() {
                drawTriangle(levels,top, left, right);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {

                updateGraphics(true);
                super.succeeded();
            }

            @Override
            protected void failed() {

                updateGraphics(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch("13");
    }
}
```

The output is as expected :
[image: triangles]

The problems I have:

a. The time printout at `updateGraphics()` shows **long** before (8 seconds on my machine) the drawing of the triangles is completed, hence it doesn't measure the complete process. How do I improve it ?

b. On my machine it takes 30-35 seconds until the panel is completely drawn. A similar swing application takes on 4 seconds. It may suggest that there is something fundamentally wrong with my javafx implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) invokes `drawTriangle()` in the background to update a [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html). The associated [`GraphicsContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) requires that "Once a `Canvas` node is attached to a scene, it must be modified on the JavaFX Application Thread." Your deeply recursive call blocks the JavaFX Application Thread, preventing a timely screen update. In contrast, your platform's implementation of `System.out.println()` may [allow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9459657/230513) it to report in a timely way. The timing disparity is seen even without a `Task` at all.

Happily for `Canvas`, "If it is not attached to any scene, then it can be modified by any thread, as long as it is only used from one thread at a time." One approach might be suggested in [*A Task Which Returns Partial Results*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). Create a notional `Task<Image>` that updates a detached `Canvas` in the background. Periodically, perhaps at each level of recursion, [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992519/230513) the `Canvas` and publish a snapshot via [`updateValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateValue-V-). The enclosing `Pane` can listen to the task's `value` property and update an enclosed `Canvas` via `drawImage()` without blocking the JavaFX Application Thread.

Sadly, snapshot "Throws `IllegalStateException` if this method is called on a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread."

In the alternative shown below, `CanvasTask` extends `Task<Canvas>` and publishes a new `Canvas` on each iteration of a loop. The enclosing `CanvasTaskTest` listens to the `value` property and replaces the previous `Canvas` each time a new one arrives. The example below displays a series of fractal trees of increasing depth and the time needed to compose each. Note that in a `GraphicsContext`, "Each call pushes the necessary parameters onto the buffer where they will be later rendered onto the image of the `Canvas` node by the rendering thread at the end of a pulse." This allows JavaFX to leverage a platform's [rendering pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29441601/230513), but it may impose an additional overhead for a large number of strokes. In practice, tens of thousands of strokes slow rendering imperceptibly, while millions of overlapping strokes may be superfluous.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513
 */
public class CanvasTaskTest extends Application {

    private static final int W = 800;
    private static final int H = 600;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("CanvasTaskTest");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W, H);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        CanvasTask task = new CanvasTask();
        task.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Canvas> observable, Canvas oldValue, Canvas newValue) -> {
            root.getChildren().remove(oldValue);
            root.getChildren().add(newValue);
        });
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private static class CanvasTask extends Task<Canvas> {

        private int strokeCount;

        @Override
        protected Canvas call() throws Exception {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
                canvas = new Canvas(W, H);
                GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
                strokeCount = 0;
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                drawTree(gc, W / 2, H - 50, -Math.PI / 2, i);
                double dt = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000d;
                gc.fillText("Depth: " + i
                    + "; Strokes: " + strokeCount
                    + "; Time : " + String.format("%1$07.1f", dt) + " µs", 8, H - 8);
                Thread.sleep(200); // simulate rendering latency
                updateValue(canvas);
            }
            return canvas;
        }

        private void drawTree(GraphicsContext gc, int x1, int y1, double angle, int depth) {
            if (depth == 0) {
                return;
            }
            int x2 = x1 + (int) (Math.cos(angle) * depth * 5);
            int y2 = y1 + (int) (Math.sin(angle) * depth * 5);
            gc.strokeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            strokeCount++;
            drawTree(gc, x2, y2, angle - Math.PI / 8, depth - 1);
            drawTree(gc, x2, y2, angle + Math.PI / 8, depth - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it in detail. I will study it and try to implement.

Comment: Sadly, snapshot "Throws
`IllegalStateException` if this method is called on a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread." Let look at an alternate approach.

Comment: To start with I applied a detached "background" canvas, as suggested, without interim updates. When drawing is done, I use snapshot copy the background canvas to the displayed canvas. This works fine, and maybe has a better overall structure. It still does not help me solve the difference between the calculated time, and the actual time.

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: My main purpose was to have a better correlation between the measured time and actual time. This was achieved by adapting the copy - canvas technique you proposed. Updating the canvas during the process is not needed, so I copy the "background" canvas when it is completed. Thanks for the detailed explanation and answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: @c0der: Glad it helped. Are you sure you need the copy? Once the canvas is composed, you can use it directly without contention.

Comment: I could. I use the main copy to display a "working"  message, and then copy the background when it is completed.

Comment: In addition to `updateValue`, also look at `updateProgress`, `updateMessage` and `updateTitle`.