# JavaFX causing fatal SIGSEGV error

Tags: java, javafx, segmentation-fault

I am running java 8.131 on OsX 10.12.5

Using the following code

```
task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final WorkerStateEvent event) {

        }
    });
```

seems to cause this error: https://pastebin.com/GbByfDeY

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a fix. The common answer is hardware issue and wait for java update. I am posting as a last restore. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add an `InvalidationListener` to the `stateProperty` of the [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). Testing this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513) on Mac OS X 10.12.5 with Java 1.8.0_131-b11, the following listener prints `SUCCEEDED` on the console.

```
    task.stateProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
        if (task.getState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.out.println(task.getState());
        }
    });
```

Testing the same [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513) on the same machine, the following `onSucceeded` handler produces the same result.

```
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final WorkerStateEvent event) {
            System.out.println(task.getState());
        }
    });
```

The underlying cause of the segmentation fault may be elsewhere.