# What is the best way to read pixels of a JavaFX Canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, colors

I want to get the color for specific coordinates inside a `Canvas`. I already tried getting a snapshot using this code:

```
WritableImage snap = gc.getCanvas().snapshot(null, null);
snap.getPixelReader().getArgb(x, y); //This just gets the color without assigning it.
```

But it just takes too much time for my application. I was wondering if there is any other way to access the color of a pixel for which I know the coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) buffers the drawing *instructions* prescribed by invoking the methods of a [`GraphicsContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST108). There *are* no pixels to read until the `Canvas` is rendered in a later [pulse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST108), and the internal format of the instruction buffer is not exposed in the API.

If a [`snapshot()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.util.Callback,javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) of the `Canvas` is feasible, a rendered pixel may be examined using the resulting image's `PixelReader`.

```
int aRGB = image.getPixelReader().getArgb(x, y);
```

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407175/230513) focuses on a single pixel. This [example](https://github.com/trashgod/modular#blend-mode-application) displays the ARGB `BlendMode` result in a `TextField` and a `Tooltip` as the mouse moves on the `Canvas`. More examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20snapshot%20canvas).

As an alternative, consider drawing into a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141878/230513), which allows access to the image's pixels directly and via its [`WritableRaster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html). Adding the following line to this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141878/230513) outputs the expected value for opaque red in ARGB order: `ffff0000`.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bi.getRGB(50, 550)));
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Pixel
{
    private static final SnapshotParameters SP = new SnapshotParameters();
    private static final WritableImage WI = new WritableImage(1, 1);
    private static final PixelReader PR = WI.getPixelReader();

    private Pixel()
    {
    }

    public static int getArgb(Node n, double x, double y)
    {
        synchronized (WI)
        {
            Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D(x, y, 1, 1);
            SP.setViewport(r);
            n.snapshot(SP, WI);
           return PR.getArgb(0, 0);
        }
    }

    public static Color getColor(Node n, double x, double y)
    {
        synchronized (WI)
        {
            Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D(x, y, 1, 1);
            SP.setViewport(r);
            n.snapshot(SP, WI);
            return PR.getColor(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add a description with your code explaining how it solves the problem, or add comments to it