# JavaFX - get pixel color when drawing polygons on top of each other

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a project aiming to reproduce images using only a fixed number of convex hull / polygons.

I am using JavaFX to have a nice GUI.

A solution to the problem is a list of polygons drawn on a canvas, letting us obtain an image.

To evaluate the quality of the solution, I am taking the image to reproduce and the image obtained from the list of polygons and I calculate the distance between the color of each pixels.

If I have a null distance between the colors of each pixels, I can say that I reproduced the goal image.

The impletation I made of this function is really slow.

To summarize, I search, for each pixels what are the polygons that contains it and then I add their color in the correct order (I am using transparent color so order is important). 
I calculate the distance between this color and the color I try to reach (on the goal image).
I sum up these distances and that's it !

```
private void computeEval() {
    PixelReader pixelReaderSolution = image.getPixelReader();
    AtomicReference<Double> eval2 = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    IntStream.range(0, (int) image.getWidth()).parallel()
            .forEach(x -> IntStream.range(0, (int) image.getHeight()).parallel()
                    .forEach(y -> {
                        Color colorSolution = pixelReaderSolution.getColor(x, y);
                        Point2D pixel = new Point2D(x, y);
                        AtomicReference<Color> pixelColor = new AtomicReference<>();
                        pixelColor.set(null);

                        polygons.stream()
                                .filter(convexPolygon -> convexPolygon.getAsPolygon().contains(pixel))
                                .forEach(convexPolygon -> {
                                    if (pixelColor.get() == null) {
                                        pixelColor.set(convexPolygon.color);
                                    } else {
                                        pixelColor.set(addColor(pixelColor.get(), convexPolygon.color));
                                    }
                                });
                        if (pixelColor.get() == null) {
                            pixelColor.set(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        lock.lock();
                        eval2.updateAndGet(v -> v + distanceColor(colorSolution, pixelColor.get()));
                        lock.unlock();
                    }));
    evaluation = 1 - (eval2.get() / (3 * image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()));
}
```

In the past, I was using the function [snapshot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) which was fast but that forced me to compute the evaluation inside a JavaFX thread; therefore, blocking my entire GUI by putting to much computations in GUI threads.

This current solution allows me to put the computations inside a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) but it is really slow.

I am a bit stuck on this and I am wondering if anyone could have an idea for me...

I may also be using JavaFX in a wrong way.

I can give more of the code, if people are wondering what's the different function around but I'm 100% that it is this function that slow down everything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to test the final reproduced image against the original one ? When comparing two images each pixel is tested once. When checking the original image against all polygons, each pixel is tested multiple times.

Comment: That is what I was doing at the beginning.But the only way I know to do so is to add each Polygon to a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) and then to make a snapshot out of it.

But snapshot can only be used in JavaFX thread and I can't put all computations in JavaFX thread. 

Maybe there's a way to obtain an image without snapshot but I have search for it in vain...

Comment: See also [*What is the best way to read pixels of a JavaFX Canvas?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45685190/230513)