# Alternatives for paintComponent in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a question but maybe it was an old question.

I saw a class that extends JPanel and an override function called paintComponent for updating panel.

I use javafx, so i want to know is there any alternative for paintComponent?

I want to update a scene in my game loop, or when i use setScene for my stage.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no equivalent. If you add nodes to a scene graph, updating their properties will automatically result in a repaint. Alternatively, you can use a canvas, and redraw it, or possibly a `WritableImage`, and update it directly.

Comment: Two approaches are compared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44136040/230513).